# Como escanear redes WiFi en Android

Tags: android

Estoy teniendo una serie de problemas que espero me podáis resolver. Soy muy novato en Android y estoy buscando ejemplos válidos para escanear las redes WiFi con el móvil. En todos los ejemplos que le he cargado, surge el mismo problema, no encuentra nunca ninguna red, cuando no es cierto.

Ahora mismo estoy usando este código de ejemplo, que en teoría debería funcionar pero no lo hace. ¿Qué puede ser?

```
public class MainActivity extends AppCompatActivity {

private Element[] nets;
private WifiManager wifiManager;
private List<ScanResult> wifiList;
private TextView tv;

Dialog dialog;
@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);

    Toolbar toolbar = (Toolbar) findViewById(R.id.toolbar);
    setSupportActionBar(toolbar);

    FloatingActionButton fab = (FloatingActionButton) findViewById(R.id.fab);
    fab.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
        @Override
        public void onClick(View view) {
            tv = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.textView);
            tv.setText("");

            detectWifi();
            Snackbar.make(view, "Scanning wifi ...", Snackbar.LENGTH_LONG)
                    .setAction("Action", null).show();
        }
    });
}


//********************  HAM DO TIM WIFI  *********************
public void detectWifi() {
    this.wifiManager = (WifiManager)getApplicationContext().getSystemService(Context.WIFI_SERVICE);
    this.wifiManager.startScan();
    this.wifiList = this.wifiManager.getScanResults();

    Toast.makeText(this, "So wifi tim thay: " + wifiList.size(), Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();

    this.nets = new Element[wifiList.size()];//khoi tao mang nets voi so phan tu = so phan tu cua mang wifiList.
    for (int i = 0; i < wifiList.size(); i++) {

        String item = wifiList.get(i).toString();
        //Toast.makeText(this, item, Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();

        String[] mang_item = item.split(",");//cat chuoi nhan duoc thanh roi luu vao mang_item.
        String item_ssid = mang_item[0]; //lay ra chuoi "SSID: name wifi"
        String ssid = item_ssid.split(": ")[1]; //cat chuoi "SSID: name wifi" => tao thanh mang 2 phan tu la SSID va name wifi|| String ssid la ten => lay o phan tu thu 1 cua mang

        nets[i] = new Element(ssid);
    }

    AdapterElements adapterElements = new AdapterElements(this);
    ListView netList = (ListView) findViewById(R.id.lv_ssid);
    netList.setAdapter(adapterElements);
    netList.setOnItemClickListener(new AdapterView.OnItemClickListener() {
        @Override
        public void onItemClick(AdapterView<?> adapterView, View view, int i, long l) {
            //Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(), nets[i].getTitle() + "", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();

            showdialow(nets[i].getTitle());
        }
    });

    //showdialow();
}

//********************  SHOW DIALOG  *********************
public void showdialow(final String ten_wifi) {
    dialog = new Dialog(MainActivity.this);
    dialog.setTitle("Nhập mật khẩu wifi");
    dialog.setCancelable(true);
    dialog.setContentView(R.layout.dialog_layout);

    Button btn_DongY = (Button) dialog.findViewById(R.id.btn_dongy);
    Button btn_Huy = (Button) dialog.findViewById(R.id.btn_huy);
    final EditText edt_Password = (EditText) dialog.findViewById(R.id.edt_password);

    CheckBox checkBox = (CheckBox) dialog.findViewById(R.id.cb_show);
    checkBox.setOnCheckedChangeListener(new CompoundButton.OnCheckedChangeListener() {
        @Override
        public void onCheckedChanged(CompoundButton buttonView, boolean isChecked) {
            if (!isChecked){
                edt_Password.setTransformationMethod(PasswordTransformationMethod.getInstance());
            }
            else {
                edt_Password.setTransformationMethod(HideReturnsTransformationMethod.getInstance());
            }
        }
    });

    btn_DongY.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
        @Override
        public void onClick(View v) {
            String matkhau = edt_Password.getText().toString();

            if (TextUtils.isEmpty(matkhau)) {
                edt_Password.setError("chưa nhập password");
            }
            else{
                Toast.makeText(MainActivity.this, "Tên wifi: " + ten_wifi + " Mat khau: " + matkhau, Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
                dialog.dismiss();
            }
        }
    });
    btn_Huy.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
        @Override
        public void onClick(View v) {
            dialog.dismiss();
        }
    });
    dialog.show();
}


class AdapterElements extends ArrayAdapter<Object> {
    Activity context;

    public AdapterElements(Activity context) {
        super(context, R.layout.items, nets);
        this.context = context;
    }

    public View getView(int position, View convertView, ViewGroup parent) {
        LayoutInflater inflater = context.getLayoutInflater();

        View item = inflater.inflate(R.layout.items, null);
        TextView tvSsid = (TextView) item.findViewById(R.id.tvSSID);

        tvSsid.setText(nets[position].getTitle());

        return item;
    }
}
```

Muchas gracias a todos de antemano.

Comment: Igual es un poco tonta lo que te voy a preguntar pero hay que asegurarse de todo, ¿estás ejecutando este código en un emulador o en un smartphone?

Comment: En el teléfono. He probado con dos diferentes por si era eso y ocurre lo mismo.

Comment: tienes puestos los permisos necesarios en el manifest?

Comment: Sí. Están puestos ambos

Comment: He probado tu código y a mi también me da 0 redes, prueba la respuesta que te acabo de poner que a mi me ha funcionado

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Tienes que hacer lo siguiente, declaras estas variables:

```
WifiManager wifi;
String wifis[];
WifiScanReceiver wifiReciever;
```

Ahora, tienes que declarar esta clase:

```
private class WifiScanReceiver extends BroadcastReceiver {
    public void onReceive(Context c, Intent intent) {
        List<ScanResult> wifiScanList = wifi.getScanResults();
        wifis = new String[wifiScanList.size()];

        for(int i = 0; i < wifiScanList.size(); i++){
            wifis[i] = ((wifiScanList.get(i)).toString());
        }
    }
}
```

Escribiendo esto ahora debería recuperarte las redes wifi disponibles:

```
wifi=(WifiManager)getSystemService(Context.WIFI_SERVICE);
wifiReciever = new WifiScanReceiver();

wifiReciever.onReceive(null, null);

wifi.startScan();
```

Tienes que asegurarte que tienes los siguientes permisos en el manifest:

```
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.CHANGE_WIFI_STATE" />
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.CHANGE_NETWORK_STATE" />
```

y (aunque no se si es necesario al 100%, quiero pensar que si) tener el wifi de tu smartphone activado

Comment: Que va, no funciona. Los permisos que le he puesto son esos dos y otra más, el de ACCESS_WIFI_STATE. Me hace el escaneo y no encuentra nada.

Comment: mmm... raro se me hace, como te comento lo he probado y me ha funcionado...

Comment: Por casualidad me podrías pasar el código completo para saber en dónde cometí el fallo? Soy muy novato...

Comment: El código es el que he puesto, sin nada más. Lo que puede ser también es que la versión de Android para la que programas es que sea mayor que para Android 6, con lo cual tendrás que pedir los permisos en tiempo de ejecución. Es lo que se me ocurre

Comment: echa un ojo a esta pregunta en inglés https://stackoverflow.com/questions/32708374/bluetooth-le-scanfilters-dont-work-on-android-m le pasa con bluethoot pero trata el tema de los permisos que te digo

Comment: Pues va a ser eso. Los Android con los que los he probado son Android 6

Comment: Ya está solucionado. Le faltaba el permiso de ubicación y que fuera runtime. Muchas gracias